# How do I resize my partition in Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I had Windows 8 installed on my system, which I screwed up, and now I run Ubuntu 12.04. While installing, Ubuntu used all the 461 GB of HDD space (one partition).

Now I want to make a new partition of maybe 100 GB or so, in order to install Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu (with a dual-boot). But I can't even get a partition done. I can't change the partition in GParted either - the option is disabled.

Comment: please attach the output of sudo fdisk -l

Answer (score 4):

*You cannot resize a partition while it is in use (mounted).*
Hence its greyed out.

**To resize your partition, you would need to boot from your Ubuntu 12.04 LiveDVD**,

open Gparted, and then resize your Ubuntu partition.

Depending upon your current partition setup, you may want to shrink different partitions

If you have a large home partition (/home), you may shrink it by 100 gb, and in the free space created, create a ntfs partition which you could use for Windows.

Post your output of

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

so that I could better advice you in partitioning.

Edit-

As you stated that you only have single partition, just resize (shrink) it by 100 gb.

Comment: *"Ubuntu used all the 461 GB of HDD space (one partition)."*? Doubt you need more information...

Comment: no swap partition even ? perhaps..

Comment: @Braiam, point taken, thnx.

Comment: When I run the sudo command it asks for a password but never inputs it when I type.

Comment: the password will be typed but it will not be displayed. This is a security feature. So when asked, just type your password and press enter. If the password is correct, it will be accepted and command will execute.